# AutoCompleteBox user completed

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete

There has to be simple way of doing this that I am just not seeing.  I need to call a method that will execute when the user completes the search in the AutoCompleteBox either by keyboard or mouse.  The first solution I thought about was using the keyDown and MouseDown, that seems more work.  Putting logic to determine if a valid option is picked for both keyboard and mouse.

Is there a better way?

Edit:
With @elgonzo advice tried the SelectionChanged event.  The issue is when the user "arrows down" the list.  So for example say the user typed something in, saw the desired results 3 down in the list and uses the down arrow key.  The user would hit the down arrow key 3 times, this would result in the event firing 3 times.

Comment: Are you interested in the event when the user selects an auto-complete suggestion in the drop-down? Or what do you mean by "when the user completes the search"? Did you mean the "AutoCompleteBox completing the search/filtering in the ItemsSource for populating the drop-down"?

Comment: Two options are to put tab and enter key events onto the textbox or adding a search button next to it.

Comment: @elgonzo When the user selects an auto-complete suggestion

Comment: @Xaphann, the AutoCompleteBox has a SelectionChanged event you might use.

Comment: @elgonzo please read edit above.

Comment: @Xaphann, what should be the user action which indicates that the entering/selection of text in the AutoCompleteBox is finsished? The answer to this question will tell you what you should do. (Most likely it will be something in the way of handling keyboard/mouse events, as you already indicated; or it will be indicated by the user through another control, as Shoe suggested; or maybe something timer-related.)

Comment: @elgonzo Basically once the user is done entering/selection, the selected item will be added to a list for later and the AutoCompleteBox will be cleared

Comment: @Xaphann, but when do you deem the the user being done? That is the big question... you will have to come up with that answer... (or put differently: How do you distinguish between "*The user is not yet done entering, he might enter more characters any minute*" and "*Now the user is done entering, and will not enter further characters*")

Comment: @elgonzo the user is done when the dropbox is closed and there is a valid option in SelectedItem.  This would be be done by hitting enter on or mouse clicking on an item in the list.

Comment: @Xaphann, use IsDropDownOpen property... (when it changes from true->false, the drop-down just has closed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@elgonzo answer the question with the IsDropDownOpen property.